# How should I translate "enunciatio" to English?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ecclesiastical-latin, philosophy-terms, logic

I am currently working on translation of post-scholastic philosophical course of the 18th century. It has been read in the Novgorod Theological Seminary (located in Russian empire) that was established on the model of the Jesuit colleges, so contents of this philosophical course might be somewhat common for various Jesuit schools in Europe (especially Eastern). So, in first part of it, called "Dialectica" (Formal logic), I faced next two titles: *"CAPUT 2dum. Quid et quotuplex Enunciatio?"* and *"CAPUT 3tium. De absolutarum enunciationum oppositione."*. Should I translate *"enunciatio"* as "declarative sentence"?

Comment: I take it you don't want to do the classic "treat it as a technical term and translate it with a cognate or not at all" maneuver?

Comment: @Draconis, I thought that there might be an established term in logic which is more accurate.

Comment: Aren't those [logical propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition)? At least _enunciado_, a Spanish cognate for _enunciatio_ is used as a synonym for _proposición_.

Comment: @Rafael, thanks! You was right! I've reread the sources: there was two versions of "Dialectica". In one of them (made by teacher himself) author uses term _"propositio"_ for propositions, in other one (made by his student) he writes _"enunciatio"_. I'm sure now that these terms are synonyms, because both of them located in the same part titled _"De secunda mentis operatione"_ which means proposition in formal logic.